# How to include PHP code in an URL

Tags: php

Now I have hard coded the following, I want to pass two values to the `index.php`

```
<a href="index.php?vaccineid=VI 7038&patientid=PN001">
<?php echo $row['vaccine'];?></a>
```

I have tried to replace it with dynamic code, but in vain

```
<a href="index.php?vaccineid =<?php echo "$row['vaccineid']";?>
 &patientid=<?php echo "$_SESSION['abc']"; ?>"><?php echo $row['vaccine'];?></a>
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using array indexing inside a double-quoted string, don't put quotes around the index. So all you need to do is change

```
echo "$row['vaccineid']"
echo "$_SESSION['abc']"
```

To:

```
// Remove single-quotes around keys ['key'] => [key]
echo "$row[vaccineid]"
echo "$_SESSION[abc]"
```

Or remove the double-quotes since you are outputting just the array value:

```
echo $row['vaccineid']
echo $_SESSION['abc']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe think of using [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) from the manual:

```
<?php
$values = array(
    'vaccineid' => $row['vaccineid'],
    'patientid'=> $_SESSION['abc']
);
?>
<a href="index.php?<?php echo http_build_query($values) ?>"><?php echo  $row['vaccineid'] ?></a>
```

Check your array to make sure it's what you expect:

```
print_r($values);
```

*One final note, if you have the `$_SESSION['abc']` in the session, don't send it via `GET`, just retrieve it from the session at the time you process the `vaccineid` on the next page.*

Comment: Nice answer. You have a typo in the array key on line 3. Should be 'vaccineid'

Answer (score 1):

Your variable not parse inside double quotes.

```
<a href="index.php?vaccineid=<?php echo urlencode($row['vaccineid']));?>&patientid=<?php echo $_SESSION['abc']; ?>"><?php echo $row['vaccine'];?></a>
```

Edit : Also you need to encode the `vaccineid` since it contains contains blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

try using html entities
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

such as passing in things like this in

```
&lt;?php echo "blablabla"; ?>
```

which gives the value   <?php echo "blablabla"; ?>